# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'header')

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1z6Py.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIyLN.png)

```
app.js:213 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'header')
    at getSlot (vuedraggable.js:59:1)
    at computeChildrenAndOffsets (vuedraggable.js:65:1)
    at Proxy.render (vuedraggable.js:163:1)
    at renderComponentRoot (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:820:1)
    at ReactiveEffect.componentUpdateFn [as fn] (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5749:1)
    at ReactiveEffect.run (reactivity.esm-bundler.js:178:1)
    at instance.update (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5862:1)
    at setupRenderEffect (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5870:1)
    at mountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5660:1)
    at processComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js:5613:1)
```

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77534025/edit) your question and include the relevant code as formatted [text not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/6225326)

Comment: also add information on relevant libraries and versions being used.  an explanation of your code and what you're trying to do and what you think caused the error wouldn't hurt either.

Answer (score 0):

With not enough information to be fully sure, it seems like you are using a version of the vuedraggable library that is not fully compliant with Vue3.

The issue you are describing comes forward searching for it (https://github.com/SortableJS/Vue.Draggable/issues/1184), the maintainers of the vuedraggable component are advising to use https://github.com/SortableJS/vue.draggable.next with Vue3.